# 2d lists in python if statements not working

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to create a 2D list in python that allows you to search for the number of wins, draws and losses of the top 5 teams in the premier league. So far I have:

```
league = [["20","14","14","12","11"],["2","5","4","8","5"],
["0","3","4","2","5"]]
team = input("Do you want to know Manchester City, Machester United, 
Chelsea, Liverpool or Tottenham Hotspur").lower
if team == "manchester city":
    teamNum = 0
elif team == "manchester united":
    teamNum = 1
elif team == "chelsea":
    teamNum = 2
elif team == "liverpool":
    teamNum = 3
elif team == "tottenham hotspur":
    teamNum = 4

winDrawLoss = input("Do you want to know wins, draws or losses?").lower
if winDrawLoss == "wins":
    print(league[0][teamNum])
elif winDrawLoss == "draws":
    print(league[1][teamNum])
elif winDrawLoss == "losses":
    print(league[2][teamNum])
```

but my if statements are not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean they aren't working? Describe what you expect to happen and what's actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

when you assigned team, you typed lower instead of lower()